# Is it correct to state that the first number that collide in single precision is 131072.02? (positive, considering 2 digits as mantissa)

Tags: c++, floating-point

I was trying to figure it out for my audio application if `float` can be used to represent correctly the range of parameters I'll use.

The "biggest" mask it needs is for frequency params, which is positive, and allow max two digits as mantissa (i.e. from 20.*00* hz to 22000.*00* hz). Conceptually, the following digits will be rounded out, so I don't care for them.

So I made this [script](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58ce6007e007c80a) to check the first number that collide in single precision:

```
float temp = 0.0;
double valueDouble = 0.0;
double increment = 1e-2;

bool found = false;
while(!found) {
    double oldValue = valueDouble;
    valueDouble += increment;
    float value = valueDouble;

    // found
    if(temp == value) {
        std::cout << "collision found: " << valueDouble << std::endl;
        std::cout << "   collide with: " << oldValue << std::endl;
        std::cout << "float stored as: " << value << std::endl;
        found = true;
    }

    temp = value;        
}
```

and its seems its `131072.02` (with `131072.01`, stored as the same `131072.015625` value), which is far away than 22000.00. And it seems I would be ok using float.

But I'd like to understand if that reasoning is correct. It is?

The whole problem would be if I set a param of XXXXX.YY (`7 digits`) and it collides with some other numbers having a less number of digits (because `single precision` only guarantee `6 digits`)

Note: of course numbers such as `1024.0002998145910169114358723163604736328125` or `1024.000199814591042013489641249179840087890625` collide, and they are within the interval, but they do it at a longer significative digits than my required mantissa, so I don't care.

Comment: @JHBonarius where do you see him complaining?

Comment: For background, have a read of this: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/  and also these: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/  (not my blog)

Comment: "i.e. from 20.00 hz to 22000.00 hz" - What you **should** be using is an integer in centihertz. That integer will have the range `[2000, 2200000]`, and no rounding problems, whatsoever. Why? Because `float` cannot even represent `0.2` correctly!

Comment: "max two digits as mantissa (i.e. from 20.00 hz to 22000.00 hz)". Eh, no, that's not two digits mantissa. `22000.00 Hz`  would be `2.200000E5`, so mantisssa is 7 digits, and the exponent is one digit. Except for the small bit where computers use base 2 and bits, not base 10 and digits.

Answer (score 3):

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [Single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) is defined as

- 1 sign bit
- 8 exponent bits: range 2^-126 to 2^127 ~ 10^-38 to 10^38)
- 23 fraction (mantissa) bits: decimal precision depending on the exponent)

At 22k the exponent will represent an offset of 16384=2^14, so the 23-bit mantissa will give you a precision of 2^14/2^23= 1/2^9 = 0.001953125... which is sufficient for your case.

For 131072.01, the exponent will represent an offset 131072 = 2^17, so the mantissa will give a precision of 2^17/2^23 = 1/2^6 = 0.015625 which is larger then your target precision of 0.01

Comment: An explanation of why the OP's test is disagreeing (accumulated error) would improve this answer.

Comment: @Yakk Is this what you mean?

Comment: Since we deal with relative precision, no use to deal with the inexact fractions found in the question. IOW, with 24 bits, all the integers up to ~16 million can be represented exactly in single precision float. Since the OP only require 2,200,000 centi-Hertz, that's more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not verify exactly what you want, but your underlying reasoning should be ok.

The problem with the program is that valueDouble will accumulate slight errors (since 0.01 isn't represented accurately) - and converting the string "20.01" to a floating point number will introduce slight round-off errors.

But those errors should be on the order of DBL_EPSILON and be much smaller than the error you see.

If you really wanted to test it you would have to write "20.00" to "22000.00" and scan them all using the scanf-variant you plan to use and verify that they differ.

Comment: The "error accumulation" doesn't matter, as the result (as printed)  accounts for that error. Error accumulation only means that `131072` won't be reached in exactly `13107200` steps.

Comment: @MSalters: The error accumulation does matter (in general, not necessarily with the specific numbers in this case). It means the values in `valueDouble` will not be the numbers the OP intended to test. In theory, there could be some point where the numbers being tested should be a and b but the errors result in testing a+e0 and b+e1, and a and b collide while a+e0 and b+e1 do not, or vice-versa, so the result is wrong. The test for a collision is done prior to printing anything, so conversion for output has no effect on the tests.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That doesn't make sense. `x` and `x+0.01` collide, as soon as `x+0.01` differs only in the 25th bit. Recall how addition works: the smallest number has its exponent adjusted to the largest number, shifting its mantissa to the right. As soon as that shift is 25 places, you're adding 0, and you have a collision. All numbers `x` with that same magnitude will cause the same "shift 25 places, add 0"

Comment: @MSalters: First, if you have `x` and `x+.01`, they do not differ by .01, since `x+.01` necessarily has a rounding error in binary floating-point. So `x` and `x+0.01` might differ in the 25th bit while `x` and `x`+.01 do not differ in the 25th bit. Second, even if both the pair `x` and `x+.01` and the pair `x` and `x`+.01 differ in the 25th bit, `x` has some accumulated error, and it is standing in place of the ideal *y* we would have at this point in the program, and *y* and *y* + .01 might not differ in the 25th bit even though `x` and `x`+.01 do, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to state that the first number that collide in single precision is 131072.02? (positive, considering 2 digits <strike>as mantissa</strike> after the decimal point)

Yes.

---

> I'd like to understand if that reasoning is correct. It is?

For values just less than 131072.0f, each successive representable `float` value is 1/128th apart.

For values in the range [131072.0f ... 2*131072.0f), each successive representable `float` value is 1/64th apart.

With values of the decimal textual form "131072.xx", there are 100 combinations, yet only 64 differ `float`.  It is not surprising that 100-64 or 36 [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) occurs - see below.  For numbers of this form, this is the first place the density of `float` is too sparse: the least significant bit in `float` > 0.01 in this range.

---

```
int main(void) {
  volatile float previous = 0.0;
  for (long i = 1; i <= 99999999; i++) {
    volatile float f1 = i / 100.0;
    if (previous == f1) {
      volatile float f0 = nextafterf(f1, 0);
      volatile float f2 = nextafterf(f1, f1 * 2);
      printf("%f %f %f    delta fraction:%f\n", f0, f1, f2, 1.0 / (f1 - f0));
      static int count = 100 - 64;
      if (--count == 0) return 0;
    }
    previous = f1;
  }
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Output

```
131072.000000 131072.015625 131072.031250    delta fraction:64.000000
131072.031250 131072.046875 131072.062500    delta fraction:64.000000
131072.046875 131072.062500 131072.078125    delta fraction:64.000000
...
131072.921875 131072.937500 131072.953125    delta fraction:64.000000
131072.937500 131072.953125 131072.968750    delta fraction:64.000000
131072.968750 131072.984375 131073.000000    delta fraction:64.000000
```

---

[Why floating-points number's significant numbers is 7 or 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961957/2410359) may also help.